# Changing colors of signs in a page with HTML5 and CSS

Tags: css, html

I have links in my website. And I want them to look like the following when I create a new one.

```
I'm going to buy a [Nintendo Switch] later this year.
```

The paragraph text is black, link text is blue and brackets text is red.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to the community :) This seems like  a pretty straightforward question buddy . What challenges are you facing while trying to implement this?

Comment: Your problem is only "Paragraph text is black, link text is blue and brackets text is red."?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following solution using `:before` and `:after` pseudo-element:

```css
a, a:link {
  color:blue;
}
a.w-brackets:before {
  content:'[';
  color:red;
}
a.w-brackets:after {
  content:']';
  color:red;
}
```

```html
I'm going to buy a <a class="w-brackets" href="http://www.nintendo.com/switch/">Nintendo Switch</a> later this year.
```